# Is possible to assign a different approver to AP bill

Tags: acumatica

An existing bill has an approval record, due to normal approval map.  With the help of SQL, I updated the value EPApproval.ownerID, and assigned a new approver.  Next, I logged in as the user who is associated with the updated owner ID.  Finally I can Approve the bill.  I wanted to see if it's possible to achieve the same success via ACM Framework.  The client has some cases in which an employee delegate must be assigned as the document approver.  Currently it isn't possible to edit the approval record via UI.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are aware of this, but in Acumatica it is possible to approve the following documents:

- Those assigned to you.
- Those assigned to other users of your workgroup.
- Escalated documents assigned to users of workgroups that are at lower levels in the company tree but in the node of your workgroup.

Refer to https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=1fe1afcc-e676-466e-8c3f-cbf64857e32a

Therefore, it might be possible to achieve what you need through the use of workgroups and proper configuration of the Organization Chart.

Unfortunately, Acumatica does not have delegate functionality. You might consider upvoting this entry on the Acumatica Ideas site (as it has already been raised previously): https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-2162

Regarding your question on whether it is possible to change the Approver, you should be able to develop this as a Customization. For example you could consider doing a Custom screen (or perhaps customize an existing screen) from where you can add this functionality. You can consider using PXDatabase.Update as well to update the entry (although this shouldn't be used in case you are doing a solution which is to be ISV certified)